# Javascript Program is freezing on a certain keypress. Why?

Tags: javascript

So I'm creating this text based RPG in JavaScript and after I create a name and enter `y` into the prompt the program freezes. Can someone please help me out? The problem seems to be when I confirm the name and it changes the `settingTheName` variable to another number and passes it through to the `uiPrompt` function it just freezes up. I have no idea why this is happening.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Random RPG</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="text"></p>
<input id="prompt"/>
<button id='butoon' onclick="uiPrompt(options,functions)">Enter</button>
<script>

var settingTheName = 0;

//used for ui to determine in certain prompts which commands are acceptable
var options;
//the input that the player puts in the ui box
var playerInput;
var functions= {
        newGame: function() {
                document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Welcome to the world of Aldania, a magical and mystical world where anything can happen! Aldania is filled with adventure so grab a sword, some Mountain Dew, Doritos, and click the link below to download some free ram! Just Kidding! We are going to create a new character for you! Lets start with his name.';
            settingTheName = 1;
        },
        loadGame: function() {
                document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Welcome to the world of Aldania, a magical and mystical world where anything can happen! Aldania is filled with adventure so grab a sword, some Mountain Dew, Doritos, and click the link below to download some free ram! Just kidding! Just create a fucking character aoadBSIHBIYCBSIY the game.';
        },
        setName: function() {
            playerInput = document.getElementById("prompt").value;
            document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Are you sure you want your character to be named ' +playerInput+ '? Press Y for yes and N for No.';
            options= {
                createTheChar:  ['y', 'yes'],
                newGame: ['n', 'no']
            };
        },
        creeteTheChar: function() {
            for (var j=0; j < 7; ++j ) {
                if (j=0) {
                    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Do you prefer to channel your power with your faith in God or the Devil?';
                } else if (j=1) {
                    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Whats your favorite element? Fire, Cold, Lightning, or Poison?';
                } else if (j=2) {
                    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Are you more of a guy who is very defensive or more ferocious?';
                } else if (j=3) {
                    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Would you like to run around yelling incantations and throwing magic missiles or unleash the power of the mind upon your foes?';
                } else if (j=4) {
                    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'When keeping undercover, do you use the shadows to your advantage or speedily sneak around?';
                } else if (j=5) {
                    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Are you the happy go lucky type of guy or do you prefer to meticulously calculate your plans?';
                } else if (j=6) {
                    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Do you wanna play a super silly character?';

                }               
            }
        }
};

//handles user input
function uiPrompt () {
    playerInput = document.getElementById("prompt").value;
    if (settingTheName == 1) {
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Are you sure you want your character to be named ' +playerInput+ '? Press Y for yes and N for No.';
        options= {
            creeteTheChar: ['y', 'yes'],
            newGame: ['n', 'no']
        };
        settingTheName = 2;
    } else {
        for (functionName in options) {
            // check if playerInput is in options[functionName] array
            if (options[functionName].indexOf(playerInput) >= 0) {
                    functions[functionName]() // call function
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

//start menu at the beginning of the game
function startMenu () {
    options= {
        newGame:  ['n', 'new game', 'game'],
        loadGame: ['l', 'load game', 'game']
    };
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'RANDOM RPG: Where everything is random as f***! \n (N)ew Game \n (L)oad Game';
}

startMenu();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `creeteTheChar` function is setting j to each of the values 0-6 instead of comparing it to each of those values.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'creeteTheChar' function needs to use == instead of just = when checking if a variable is equal to a value. Otherwise, you are setting the value each time. This is causing your function to loop infinitely because j will always be less than 7.

You also want to increment j after each iteration and not before. So instead ++j you do j++. If you don't do this, j==0 will never be true. Also, the creeteTheChar function isn't waiting for any user input before moving on to the next iteration in the loop. So it ends up finishing the loop immediately and 'Do you wanna play a super silly character?' is displayed.

Not to discourage you, but you'll want your code to be more dynamic if you intend on having a lot of choices. Otherwise you will end up with mountains of procedural code that is impossible to manage and track bugs through. To do it properly, you'll want to make use of classes.

Anyways, here's the creeteTheChar function properly evaluating the value of j:

```
    creeteTheChar: function() {
        console.log('creating character');
        for (var j=0; j < 7; j++ ) {
            if (j==0) {
                document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Do you prefer to channel your power with your faith in God or the Devil?';
            } else if (j==1) {
                document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Whats your favorite element? Fire, Cold, Lightning, or Poison?';
            } else if (j==2) {
                document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Are you more of a guy who is very defensive or more ferocious?';
            } else if (j==3) {
                document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Would you like to run around yelling incantations and throwing magic missiles or unleash the power of the mind upon your foes?';
            } else if (j==4) {
                document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'When keeping undercover, do you use the shadows to your advantage or speedily sneak around?';
            } else if (j==5) {
                document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Are you the happy go lucky type of guy or do you prefer to meticulously calculate your plans?';
            } else if (j==6) {
                document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Do you wanna play a super silly character?';

            }
        }
    }
```